# Calculate distance (km) between point within multipolygon and nearest edge

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have MariaDB with geographic points and multi-polygons representing country borders. I need to calculate the nearest distance between one point within the country and its closest border.

My example MultiPolygon: https://pastes.io/2ysfjoz3jy

My query:

```
Select st_distance(point(107.876273,21.559037), ST_ExteriorRing(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(mymultipolygon_above)))
```

The result is NULL though. Why? Does ST_ExteriorRing only work with single polygons? How can I get this working with multipolygons?

Simply using st_distance with the multipolygon wouldn't work because the point is inside the polygon and therefore the resulting distance is always 0:

```
Select st_distance(point(107.876273,21.559037), ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(mymultipolygon_above))
```